# Nokogiri XML Builder Newlines

Tags: xml, newline, nokogiri

Nokogiri XML Builder is randomly adding new lines to the outputted XML.

How can I get Nokogiri to output a new line after each tag.

For example, the output I am getting is

```
<books>
   <book>
      <title>foobar</title><author>Me
      </author>
   <book>
</books>
```

but i want

```
<books>
   <book>
      <title>foobar</title>
      <author>Me</author>
   <book>
</books>
```

WHAT IS WRONG!!!!???

Comment: @user562688 What version of Ruby and Nokogiri are you using? IIRC there was a bug with a Java-only version of Nokogiri under JRuby, but I thought it had been fixed.

Comment: Syntactically, both examples are the same except for a trailing `"\n"` after the text in the `<author>` node. `<title>` on a separate line from `<author>` is inconsequential as far as moving the XML content.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in your code, but, because you said "No, I can't. I just need an explanation." we can't help you fix it.

This generates the output you want. You'll need to figure out how to make it apply to your situation:

```
require 'nokogiri'

builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.books {
    xml.book {
      xml.title { xml.text 'foobar' }
      xml.author { xml.text 'Me' }
    }
  }
end

puts builder.to_xml
# >> <?xml version="1.0"?>
# >> <books>
# >>   <book>
# >>     <title>foobar</title>
# >>     <author>Me</author>
# >>   </book>
# >> </books>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with the jRuby version of Nokogiri. I've confirmed it as being present on jRuby 1.6.3 with 1.5.0.beta.2

Try updating to the latest version to see if that resolves the problem, if not you'll likely just have to wait or deal with it in the meantime.